# How to Override JQUERY-UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, overriding

I found this link : https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/1480

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
        console.log("override");
        _allowInteraction: function(event) {
            if(this._super(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return $(event.target).hasClass('copyPaste');
        },
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I try to put that block code in my `$(document).ready()`, and I've put that into separated js file, right after jquery.min.js and jquery-ui.js.
This is the snippet :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /**
     * overriding jqueryui dialog
     */
    (function($) {
        $.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
            _allowInteraction: function(event) {
                console.log("override");
                if(this._super(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return $(event.target).hasClass('copyPaste');
            },
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

But, after I refresh my browser, and try to open the jquery dialog, browser console not logging the "override" string.
So I guess my override code didn't performed well (or not at all)
So how can I override my jquery-ui dialog, with that code, so that my jquery-ui dialog will be affected with that code?

Comment: AFAIK `ready` handlers are not guaranteed to be executed in any particular order. Could you make a MCVE? Anyway, it's better to create your own widget, eg. `$.widget("my.customDialog"...` than to overwrite the library one

Comment: What is MCVE anyway? Sorry I'm a newbie

Comment: Lets say I can create MCVE (which I don't know what that stands for), and I create my own widget, how can I use my widget, I mean, I think that will be as dizzy as my problem, overriding the jquery function. I don't know how to override this widget properly, what the step, and this is goes same to create and using my own widget

Comment: [The FAQ explains creating a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As for [using a derived widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/), you use it the same way you're currently using the overwritten dialog (eg. `$(selector).customDialog(...)`)